# Method of payment from the Square SDK in Response

Tags: ios, objective-c, square-connect

**Is there a way to get back the method of payment from the Square SDK?**

I see the following data on a Square-Connect Response:

```
{
      "client_transaction_id" = "AC0AA810-E7F5-4D6B-A4C7-28C3C4A149C4";
      status = ok;
      "transaction_id" = ZHMpZaIy47IcqJfMXggoqa6eV;
}
```

But is there a way to add the method of payment that was used to the returnable package? ie *Cash*, *Credit*, *Gift Card*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Square's REST APIs to retrieve details about the transaction. See https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v1/#get-paymentid and https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2/#endpoint-retrievetransaction